# create collage images view gallery in android

Tags: android

I would like to make 10 images in collage format the sample layout is given bellow:

[image]

this is sample image I would like to make this type of collection of images
and also some ability I would like to implement in my project is given bellow:

1) when I touch on any image it come in front.

2) zoom image

3) move image any where in screen

4) delete image on long press

if any one have idea to implement this type of view then most well come to share with me.

Comment: https://github.com/johannoren/PhotoCollage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick results :

Public repository for this : https://github.com/thuytrinh/android-collage-views

Answer (score 1):

Setup zoom button for the touch zoom
use context menu for long press delete
or you can use buttons that was easy to setup with onclicklistener